# How to "click to chat" whatsapp groups or multiple numbers

Tags: html, api, url, whatsapp

I find the click to chat function of Whatsapp extremely useful. 
As you all know, it is very simple. Just type:

```
    https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=XXXXXXXXXX&text=example
```

(where XXXXXXXXXX stands for any number starting with country code, without zero or plus, and the rest of the number) in the URL, and the trick is done.

I wonder if there is a way to send the same message to TWO OR MORE numbers at the same time!

Imagine one could type:

```
    /send?phone=44785XXXXX1&/send?phone=44785XXXXX2 (doesn't work) or
    /send?phone=44785XXXXX1&44785XXXXX2 (doesn't work) or
    /send?phone=44785XXXXX1?phone=44785XXXXX2 (doesn't work) or
    /send?groupID=EXAMPLEGROUPID  (obviously doesn't work).
```

Initially I thought I could make a URL to a separate website with a link containing two window.open bits as in:

onclick="window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=4478XXXXXX8&text=Hello%20Vanni!','newwin') onclick="window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=44785XXXXX1&text=Hello%20Vanni!','newwin');">click me

but that opens two window or tabs, and is less useful than both numbers being contacted AT THE SAME TIME WITHIN THE SAME TAB, from the same URL.

Do you think this is possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you got way around it ?, If so kindly share it.